# I want these if else statements to be shorten up

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements

```
    if isLeapYear:
        if month == 2:
            return 29
        elif month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 9 or month == 11:
            return 30
        else:
            return 31
    else:
        if month == 2:
            return 28
        elif month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 9 or month == 11:
            return 30
        else:
            return 31
```

I want these if else statement to shorten up
both else if and else stament in both if and else stament are same
is there any way i could shorten these up

Answer (score 0):

You could use only an if..else and return the result of a conditional operation

```py
isLeapYear = True

def getMonthDays (month):
  if month == 2:
    return 29 if isLeapYear else 28 
  else:
    return 30 if month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 9 or month == 11 else 31


print(getMonthDays(2))   # 29
print(getMonthDays(4))   # 30
print(getMonthDays(12))  # 31
```

the conditional (ternary operation) being: `return "yes" if Statement else "no"`

To additionally simplify the longer line:

```py
isLeapYear = True

def getMonthDays (month):
  if month == 2:
    return 29 if isLeapYear else 28 
  else:
    return 30 if month in [4, 6, 9, 11] else 31
    

print(getMonthDays(2))   # 29
print(getMonthDays(4))   # 30
print(getMonthDays(12))  # 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really simplifying your if/else constructs, but most likely an easier solution to the question itself.  Unless this is homework ;)

```
import calendar

_weekday, nof_days = calendar.monthrange(1999,2)
print(nof_days)
```

=> 28

See [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the isLeapYear returns either True or False,
You could try below logic,

```
   if isLeapYear==True and month == 2:
        return 29
    elif isLeapYear==False and month == 2:
        return 28
    elif (isLeapYear==True or isLeapYear==False) and month in [4,6,9,11]:
        return 30
    else:
        return 31
```